# Is there is a way I can save my table in ascending order by id

Tags: sql

Is there is a way. I can save my table in ascending order by id.

I want to create new table from existing table for that I am using. SELECT id,name into newtable from oldtable order by id asc. So it create the table but new table doesnot store in ascending order by id. I want to store the id in ascending order in new table.

````sql
SELECT AirlineData2019.[id]
      ,AirlineData2019.[DestAirportID]
      ,AirlineData2019.[DestAirportSeqID]
      ,AirlineData2019.[DestCityMarketID]
      ,AirlineData2019.[Dest]
      ,AirlineData2019.[DestCityName]
      ,AirlineData2019.[DestState]
      ,AirlineData2019.[DestStateFips]
      ,AirlineData2019.[DestStateName]
      ,AirlineData2019.[DestWac] 
 INTO Destination FROM AirlineData2019 ORDER BY id;
```[![I want to save my data in that way in new table][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0h0t.png
````

Comment: In a relational database, rows are *unordered*. There is no inherent ordering, until you use an `order by` clause.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So storing them in an "order" doesn't really make sense.  Actually, most databases support clustered indexes, which do have an ordering.

But even with a clustered index, this does not do what you want -- because queries on the table are not guaranteed to return the results in a particular order *unless* you use an `order by`.

I would recommend that you define the `id` column as the primary key -- or at least create an index on it.  Then when you use `order by id`, the query will use the index.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer - no.

SQL tables are inherently unordered. If you want to retrieve the rows in some particular order, you'll just have to use an `order by` clause when you query it (like your original query did).